# How to enable MultiViews in Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, multiviews

I was trying to achieve that, If someone opens the URL
/login then It should open the  /login/index.php file.
and it requires that multiviews needs to be enabled, I found the below options

1.`Adding in the .htacces`

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

2. Add the multiview option to your apache conf file, like below

   ```
    <Directory /var/www/sites/foo/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
   ```

but these solutions didn't work.

Comment: "/login then It should open the /login/index.php" - this has nothing to do with MultiViews (which is part of mod_negotiation, as your first example suggests). To achieve this you would need to set `DirectoryIndex index.php` (part of mod_dir - a _base_ module), as in your second example. (Your first example explicitly disabled MultiViews anyway.) What was actually happening when `/login` was requested? Did you restart Apache after making changes to the server config? Did you edit the correct place in the server config?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for the comments.
- I edited the question and removed the - before Multiviews, It was mistakenly added.
- I restarted the server many times and edited the correct files
- but when I made the changes in the mime.conf, I got the desired results

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the below solution that worked for me, hope It will help someone else too.

Here is the solution :

open the below file

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf
```

Find the below line in the file

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .html .htm
```

Uncomment(If commented) and add .php If It does not contain it.
Restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This would imply that Apache was not configured to parse `.php` files? However, doing this is no different than the second example in your question, which would perhaps imply you were either editing the wrong file or did not restart Apache?